# SQL clause where id exists X times in alternate table

Tags: sql, if-statement, count

I've attempted creating an SQL query which only selects rows from `database1.documents` which has a `doc_id` which is equal to the 'id' that appears less than 3 times in `database2.documents`.

Database2.documents uses a foreign ID (database2.documents.doc_id = database1.documents.id).

I have cut down my query to the basic concept:

```
SELECT database1.documents.id, database1.documents.title, database1.documents.date
  FROM database1.documents
 WHERE COUNT (database1.documents.id = database2.documents.doc_id) < 3
```

Here's an example of the desired outcome:

```
+---------------------------+
| Database 1: 'documents'   |
|---------------------------|
| id | title   | date       |
|----+---------+------------|
|  1 | Title 1 | 01/01/2011 |
|  2 | Title 2 | 02/01/2011 |
|  3 | Title 3 | 03/01/2011 |
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
| Database 2: 'documents'   |
|---------------------------|
| id | doc_id | date        |
|----+--------+-------------|
|  1 | 2      | 01/01/2011  |
|  2 | 3      | 02/01/2011  |
|  3 | 2      | 03/01/2011  |
|  4 | 2      | 04/01/2011  |
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
| Result                    |
|---------------------------|
| id | title   | date       |
|----+---------+------------|
|  1 | Title 1 | 01/01/2011 |
|  3 | Title 3 | 03/01/2011 |
+---------------------------+
```

It doesn't work, how do I go about achieving this? A word of guidance would be most appreciated, thank you. :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition based on aggregate functions should be put in `HAVING`, not `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT d1.id, d1.title, d1.date, COUNT(*)
FROM database1.documents d1
LEFT JOIN database2.documents d2 ON (d1.id = d2.doc_id)
GROUP BY d1.id, d1.title, d1.date 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

Another alternative is to use derived queries as it was suggested by others

Answer (score 0):

```
--  here's how to get the docid's from d2 that happen 3 times.

select *
from database1.document d1,
(
select count(*), d2.documentid
from database2.document d2
group by d2.documentid
having count(*) >= 3
) ds2
where ds2.documentid = d1.documentid
```

Comment: group by is required to allow you to count how many times the id exists. having is for filtering out the records that happen less than 3 times. i put it in a sub query in the form to join it with the d1. and the join is an inner join which will restrict the results to ones that match.

Comment: The syntax worked the wrong way around and instead gave me only those which doc_id's in database2. Thank you anyway ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM database1.documents a LEFT JOIN 
       (
         SELECT  doc_id, COUNT(1) cnt_docs
           FROM  database2.documents 
          GROUP BY   doc_id
       ) b
    ON a.id = b.doc_id 
   AND b.cnt_docs < 3
```